Romance book series about a part-angel protagonist with monsters after her
The series had at least 3 books in it. I remember the first book being free on the Apple Books store when I read it. This was somewhere between 2012 and 2016.
The cover was green and had a woman on the front. The most distinct feature I can remember about it is that one of her hands kinda faded into a magic glow (that looked like one big spike instead of a hand. Had nothing to do with the plot).
The plot was about a female protagonist somewhere in her 20s or 30s (or at least, out of high school). I'm pretty sure it was about angels and she was part angel, but they weren’t sure about it at first.
Monsters are after her, and she has to be protected by other angels until she transforms/awakens. The angels have either silver or gold blood.
She ends up with one of the guy angels that is trying to protect her.
I think she ends up dying or something in the 2nd or 3rd book, but comes back/heals not long after. However, she ends up with different blood than the other angels (again, it was either silver or gold. So if the angels had silver blood, then hers is now gold or the other way round).
I don't think there was a love triangle. I don't think it was smutty, but I also don't think it was young adult.

https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/872333.Blue_Bloods?

There is a slim chance you're thinking of The Dark Elements series by Jennifer L. Armentrout.  Your description sounded very familiar to me, and I racked my Amazon library looking for it.  This is the match I came up with.  The significant difference, though, is that instead of Angels, the side of good is upheld by Gargoyles (or, as they call themselves, Wardens).  That said, they seemed to be pretty much Angelic stand-ins to me.
In White Hot Kiss Layla is half-demon, half-Warden.  The Wardens, in general, treat her with distrust even though they raised her; among other things, she drains the soul of people she kisses.  But she seems to want to be on the side of good.
She has a thing for Zayne, a Warden, but Zayne views himself as her protector.
Angels do exist in this universe, superior to the Wardens, and kind of jerks.  Holier-than-thou, if you will.
Wardens and Demons have human forms and alternate forms.  I don't find anything about blood colors, but Wardens are gray, Demons are black, and Layla - when she shifts into her alternate form - is a mix:

My skin was black and gray, marbleized in a shifting blend of both species.  A beautiful mixture of the Warden and the demon long since buried deep inside of me.

The other two books are Stone Cold Touch and Every Last Breath.
That's about all I remember from my attempt to read it - I stopped partway through.  From the Amazon page I read there is a triangle with a demon named Roth.  And that Layla will be pivotal to a prophecy.
